# Able to access file using java.io.File but not using jcifs.smb.SmbFile

Tags: java, file, io, ntlm, smb

I have a shared resource \machineName\dir\file.txt which is shared with every one. I can access this file using java.io.File but jcifs.smb.SmbFile results in exception:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: account currently disabled
```

The reason is SMB uses GUEST user in NTLMSSP_AUTH which fails in authentication.

I can access the file when I provide authentication information like:

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", "userName", "Password");
SmbFile smbfile = new SmbFile("//machineName/dir/file.txt", auth);
```

My question is can I access the file shared with every one having read permission using SmbFile without providing authentication?

```
SmbFile smbfile = new SmbFile("//machineName/dir/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect the server via SMB you need to authenticate (user, anonymous or guest)
The connection phase have 3 steps : 
1. negotiate - connect to the server (new connection) and choose the dialect.
2. session setup - connect with the credentials.
3. tree connect - connect to the share.

- Guest connection is not recommended - try to connect with Anonymous!
  Add these steps are not related directly to the file access.
  If you have the security access(ACL) on the file that permit all users to read you should get the access to the file.